# User interface synchronization between two identical software applications running on different machines

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, desktop-application

I wrote a desktop application that runs on two different machines (machine A and machine B). The GUI of the application on machine A needs to synchronize with that on machine B when both applications are running and communicating with each other.

For example, if user 1 press a button in machine A and move to a new UI page, the same navigation needs to occur in machine B as well. The user input will be touch input only and the user will only operate on one of the machine at a time. I have a few thoughts for the implementation:

1. Approach 1 is to enumerate all UI pages as "states" and enumerate all possible events (ex. button presses). When an event occurs on machine A, it will forward the event alongside its current state to machine B before handling the event. Upon receiving the forwarded event, machine B will first ensure its current state matches that of machine A before handling the event. This will allow machine A and machine B to synchronize their GUI in an "event-driven" basis (except the initial setup to make sure they have the same starting point).
2. Approach 2 is similar to approach 1 except machine A will be sending the coordinate of the touch input to machine B in the example above. Machine B is responsible for detecting whether the touch input coordinate matches a UI control. This will eliminate the need to enumerate all the possible events but maybe tricky if the application runs on different screen size.

Please share your feedback on both approaches. I may not be thinking in the right way so any alternative are welcome as well. Please let me know if you need any clarification on my question. Thanks!

Comment: For both approaches, I think it's almost certain that the two applications will go out of sync. For instance, because the network acts up and you lose an event. The more robust way would be an approach where the full UI is rendered based on the current state (how for instance React works) and you would share the full state between the two instances. Even if you lose what state change once, the next time you successfully share the state the instances are in sync again.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It is intuitive and I actually landed with a similar model to solve this issue. Basically, I separated the UI and the core business logic to two applications. The UI application runs as separated instances in two machines to render the user interface and deliver user input to the business logic application. The business logic application executes the business logic and determines the appropriate UI update (state and data) for the UI application. There are still some technical challenges to solve but it has been a fun exercise. Thanks for the help!